# Maple: How to use partial differential operators?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, maple

I am trying to calculate the commutator $[v,w]=vw-wv$ for given infinitesimals

$$v=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$$
and

$$w=x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}$$

I know how to calculate the commutator by hand, but I would like to learn how I can do these kind of calculations with maple.

Here is the result of the calculations:

$$[v,w]=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)-x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using Lie algebra package in Maple 18, for sake of example I give you following code:

```
with(DifferentialGeometry): with(LieAlgebras):

Gamma := evalDG([D_x, D_y, x*D_x, y*D_x, x*D_y, y*D_y]);

L := LieAlgebraData(Gamma, Alg3);

DGsetup(L)

MultiplicationTable("LieTable")
```

this last command will return you Lie table for commutator.

For more details see tutorial on Lie algebra in Maple help.

You can also use command SymmetryCommutator command in PDEtools package of Maple.

For further detail see [Mapleprime](http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/211197-Lie-Algebra-To-Abstract-Lie-Algebra)

Comment: Thank you alto! Do you know by any chance a way to calculate the adjoint representation?

Comment: Adjoint can also be calculated in Lie algebra package see website http://digitalcommons.usu.edu/dg/

Comment: Thank you fort the resource. I will have a look at it :).

Comment: I can provide code if you want.

Comment: That would be great :)

Comment: How I can send  this code?

Comment: Can you upload your file and post the link here? If your code is not very long you can also post it in your answer:).

Comment: Going to sleep send you tomorrow for sure, if possible write your mail id here.